# Automatically redirect to another webpage when a website prefix is detected in Firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a simple way to redirect a webrowser (Firefox) to another website whenever the actual page starts with a prefix?

My case is with IEEEXplore, I'd like to redirect

`https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/<DOC_NUMBER>`

instead of

`https://<OUR_UNIVERSITY_IEEEXPLORE_LINK>/document/<DOC_NUMBER>`

The same with some other services, basically i need just to replace the prefix. any ideas about how to do it? preferably in Firefox.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

[webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) allows you to intercept requests and redirect them. You can also limit it to top level loads by filtering on `details.type`